# JAXBContext context path vs @XMLSeeAlso

Tags: java, jaxb

I have gotten confused by these two aspects of JAXB.

As far as I understand, when passing colon separated package names as context path to `newInstance` method of JAXBContext, JAXB will add all the classes under these packages to its scope to be used in operations like marshall/unmarshall/validate...etc.

The @XmlSeeAlso annotation instructs the JAXBContext to bind classes. All the examples I've seen use this annotation to specify only its child classes (I couldn't tell why actually).

Below are my questions:

> 1- Can the @XmlSeeAlso be omitted if the classes referred by the
>   annotation are within the packages passed to JAXBContext `newInstance`
>   method?
>
> 2- If the above is true, then why do we need this annotation in the first
>   place, where we can simply pass ALL the packages containing the classes we need to the `newInstance`
>   function?
>
> 3- If the above is not true, can we only use packages containing top
>   level classes passed to the `newInstance`, and use the annotation @XmlSeeAlso to reference all
>   children of these classes?

Comment: The package path constructor requires the presence of an ObjectFactory or a jaxb.index file. These come for free if you're compiling from xsds, but are painful to maintain if you're handcrafting. `@XmlSeeAlso` supports the use of annotation-only jaxb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- Can the @XmlSeeAlso be omitted if the classes referred by the
>   annotation are within the packages passed to JAXBContext newInstance
>   method?

yes, `@XmlSeeAlso` is used to instruct `JAXBContext` to look for classes that is not otherwise loaded by `newInstance()`. To let `JAXBContext` to know about the subclasses used, either you can specify with `@XmlSeeAlso` or pass all subclasses in the `newInstance` method.

> 2- If the above is true, then why do we need this annotation in the
>   first place, where we can simply pass ALL the packages containing the
>   classes we need to the newInstance function?

`@XmlSeeAlso` approach is used mostly when you are creating JAXB classes on your own. When you have XSD->JAXB approach, then `JAXBContext.newInstance()` with all packages separated by `:` is preferred.